# The intersection of two conics - matrix solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recently had to compute the intersection of two conics, and found it to be a long and complicated procedure. Looking at Wikipedia, the advice to [find the points of intersection of two conics in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Intersecting_two_conics), which is echoed in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175380/solution-af-a-system-of-2-quadratic-equations), is to write the conics in matrix form, say $C_1$ and $C_2$, and then solve $\det( \lambda C_1+\mu C_2)=0$ for values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then consider the degenerate conic $C_0=\lambda C_1+\mu C_2$ and the intersection of this with your original conics will be easier to compute (and coincides with the intersection of the two conics originally).

My question is: originally we were looking for the solutions of two degree 2 polynomials in two variables. How is solving $\det(\lambda C_1 + \mu C_2)=0$, a degree three polynomial in two variables, any easier (in general)? Certainly there are specific matrices $C_1$ and $C_2$ for which this is quite obvious, but in general it does not seem to me as though we have made our problem simpler.

Comment: After "echoed in the answer to this question" it might also be worth linking to another [question about the algorithm for the intersection of two conics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767225/algorithm-intersection-of-two-conics)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not "really" a polynomial in two variables: it's homogeneous in $\lambda$ and $\mu$, so really it behaves like a polynomial in one variable $\frac{\lambda}{\mu}$. The use of the homogeneous polynomial is that we don't have to artificially exclude the case that $\mu = 0$.

The essential point is the following: you want to compute the set of points satisfying $x^T C_1 x = x^T C_2 x = 0$. This is the same as computing the set of points satisfying

$$x^T (a C_1 + b C_2) x = x^T (c C_1 + d C_2) x$$

for any $a, b, c, d$ such that $ad - bc \neq 0$. Consequently it is potentially possible to simplify the problem a lot by choosing $a, b, c, d$ carefully and this determinant calculation is just one way to do that. (Also it generalizes to conics in higher dimensions.)