# The line $y+x=2$ intersects the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{16}+\dfrac{y^2}{9}=1$ at $A,B$. A circle with diameter $AB$ is drawn to intersect...

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

> The line $y+x=2$ intersects the ellipse $\dfrac{x^2}{16}+\dfrac{y^2}{9}=1$ at $A,B$. A circle with diameter $AB$ is drawn to intersect $\dfrac{x^2}{16}+\dfrac{y^2}{9}=1$ at two more points $C,D$. If the equation of the line $CD$ is $y=mx+c$, find $m$.

My thought process is to  put $y=2-x$ in the ellipse and obtain two values of $x$. Accordingly, we shall get the coordinates of $A,B$. Then we can write the equation of circle. And then we can solve it with ellipse and get $C,D$.

But when I start doing it, the calculations are not very pleasant.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The circle doesn't intersect the ellipse at two more points. Did you mean something else?

Comment: Mr. @jjm336 says is correct! Could the OP clarify the question?

Comment: Hi, I hve posted the question verbatim. Also, I think the circle will be cutting the ellipse at two more points. Ellipse cuts postive x-axis at $(4,0)$ and positive y-axis at $(0,3)$. And the given line cuts the ellipse in 2nd and 4th quadrant. From there, if we draw a circle, I think it would cut the elipse in 1st and 3rd quadrants.

Comment: The two other points are complex; the primary decomposition of the ideal of the four points is `{ideal(x+y-2,25*y^2-36*y-108), ideal(7*x-7*y-50,1225*y^2+6300*y+15444)}` so if anything $m=1.$

Answer (score 3):

The answer is $m=1$ if you allow non-real intersection points.

Consider $x+y+c=0$ and $x^2/16+y^2/9=1.$

Substitute $y=-c-x$ into $9x^2+16y^2=9\cdot 16$ and get $9x^2+16(-c-x)^2=9\cdot 16$ or $25x^2+32cx+16c^2-144=0$

Use the quadratic formula to get $y=\frac{-9c\pm\sqrt{(9c)^2-\cdot 25\cdot (9c^2-144)}}{25}=\frac{-9c\pm 12\sqrt{25-c^2}}{25}$

The coordinates of $A, B$ are $(-c-\frac{-9c+ 12\sqrt{25-c^2}}{25},\frac{-9c+ 12\sqrt{25-c^2}}{25}),(-c-\frac{-9c- 12\sqrt{25-c^2}}{25},\frac{-9c- 12\sqrt{25-c^2}}{25})$

And find the equation of the circle on diameter $AB$ as $(x-x(A))(x-x(B))+(y-y(A))(y-y(B))=0$

$x^2+y^2+(32cx)/25+(18cy)/25+(337c^2)/625-(288(25-c^2))/625=0$

Now to find the four points of intersection of the ellipse and circle set up the system $\begin{align}9&x^2+&16&y^2-9\cdot 16&=0\\16&x^2+&16&y^2+16((32cx)/25+(18cy)/25+(337c^2)/625-(288(25-c^2))/625)&=0\end{align}$

or

$\begin{align}9&x^2+&16&y^2-9\cdot 16&=0\\7&x^2+&&+16((32cx)/25+(18cy)/25+(337c^2)/625-(288(25-c^2))/625)+9\cdot 16&=0\end{align}$

The second equation can be solved for $y:$

$y = -(175x^2+512cx+400c^2-1008)/(288c)$ and be set back into equation 1:

$(30625x^4)/(5184c^2)+(2800x^3)/(81c)-(1225x^2)/(18c^2)+(4675x^2)/54+(6400cx)/81-(1792x)/(9c)+(2500c^2)/81+196/c^2-2696/9=0$

Knowing that $A, B$ are again solutions we can factor

$((25x^2+32cx+16c^2-144)(1225x^2+5600cx+10000c^2-7056))/(5184c^2)$

and the other two give $C,D$ and we have the system:

$\begin{align}9x^2+16y^2-9\cdot 16&=0\\x^2+y^2+(32cx)/25+(18cy)/25+(337c^2)/625-(288(25-c^2))/625&=0\\1225x^2+5600cx+10000c^2-7056&=0\end{align}$

Noting that $-175/18(x^2+y^2+(32/25)cx+(18/25)cy+c^2-288/25)+175/288(9x^2+16y^2-144) +1/288(1225x^2+5600cx+10000c^2-7056)=c(7x-7y+25c)=0$

So the line through $C,D$ for varying $c$ is $7x-7y+25c=0,$ which as promised gives $m=1.$

But $1225y^2-3150cy+5625c^2-7056=0$ has discriminant $-705600(5c-7)(5c+7)$

[image: non-real for c outside interval from -1.4 to 1.4]

Comment: Putting $y=2-x$ in ellipse, I get, $25x^2-64x-80=0$. From this, are we obtain to coordinates of $A,B$ and write equation of circle and solve it with ellipse, then we would get a quadratic equation whose roots would be imaginary? (Actually, I am not able to understand the formatting of your answer.)

Comment: @aarbee See the edits. Actually the ellipse and circle always intersect in four points over the complexes with multiplicities. These come out in the `primaryDecomposition` as a pair of "line and quadratic equation".

Comment: @aarbee By hand, it goes as you sketch, but for the intersection of the ellipse and circle, which needs more [care](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1777007). This usually involves a quartic. I'll update the answer with a by hand solution in due time.

Comment: In that case, $m$ should be $-1$, right?

Comment: @aarbee See the edit

Answer (score 2):

There is no other intersection point apart of $A$ and $B$. [image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Can we prove this algebraically? Or, can we draw the diagram convincingly without the help of graphic calculators?

Comment: @aarbee In maxima `solve([x+y-2,x^2/16+y^2/9-1],[x,y]);  % [[x = -(12*sqrt(21)-32)/25,y = (12*sqrt(21)+18)/25],[x = (12*sqrt(21)+32)/25,y = -(12*sqrt(21)-18)/25]]`
`ratexpand((x+(12*sqrt(21)-32)/25)*(x-(12*sqrt(21)+32)/25)+(y-(12*sqrt(21)+18)/25)*(y+(12*sqrt(21)-18)/25)); % y^2-(36*y)/25+x^2-(64*x)/25-188/25`
In M2 `R=QQ[x,y]
J=ideal(x^2/16+y^2/9-1,y^2-(36*y)/25+x^2-(64*x)/25-188/25)`
`primaryDecomposition J -- {ideal(x+y-2,25*y^2-36*y-108), ideal(7*x-7*y-50,1225*y^2+6300*y+15444)}` This means that the line through $C, D$ is $7x-7y-50=0$ or $y=x-\frac{50}{7}.$

Comment: @aarbee Note that $1225y^2+6300y+15444=0$ has non-real roots.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I think I was confused. I still haven't really got it. Any chance you could post your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

Hints: No need complicated calculation. Note that lines $AB$ and $CD$ connecting the intersections of ellipse and circle are perpendicular. This is what you have to show and get the result that :
$$x+y=2\Rightarrow m_1=-1$$

$$\Rightarrow m=\frac{-1}{m_1}=1$$

Second figure is for comparison, where line $y=2x+3$ intersect the ellipse. you can see that the line connecting other points of intersect of circle with ellipse is not perpendicular on the line intersection with it, that is they are perpendicular only if gradient of the line is $m=\pm1$.

Comment: Hi. To be honest, I had thought about the lines being perpendicular. But I couldn't find a convincing reason.

Comment: You drawing is wrong. The circle intersects the ellipse in only two points.

Comment: Hi. Can you please elaborate on your hint as to why the other line would be perpendicular to the given line, without the graphic calculator maybe? An approach that can be worked in the limited time of exam? Other answers give quite complicated calculations.

Comment: @aarbee, This is what Jan Magnus has done perfectly, but I am working on a simpler algorithm.

Comment: @aarbee ,the system of two bi-quadratic equations, one for the ellipse and one for the circle gives four solutions which gives the coordinates of intersections. You can see the solution of this kind of system of equations  in a question I answered four years ago in this site(see my answers). If two equations can be factorized then there will be four couple of equation which give the coordinates of four points of intersections.