# Line through the intersection on two conics

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

> Let 
>   $$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2dyz+2exz+2fxy=0 \\
> gx^2+hy^2+jz^2+2kyz+2lxz+2mxy=0$$ 
>   be two conics in barycentric coordinates. Can you suggest a way or algorithm to find the equation of a line passing through the point of intersection of  two conics?

I tried solving but this way not giving any progess

Can anybody suggests the way to deal this situation.

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Intersecting_two_conics) in Wikipedia. The section under Intersection of two conics. Note that they may intersect in up to 4 points. The section explains briefly how to find the degenerate conic through those points (eg a pair of intersecting lines). [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186620/the-intersection-of-two-conics-matrix-solution) touches on the matrix approach.

Comment: Thank you sir, but can u explain with an example

Comment: Maybe, could you check [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175380/solution-af-a-system-of-2-quadratic-equations) first and let me know if it is enough,

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767225/algorithm-intersection-of-two-conics)

Answer (score 0):

For convenience I will use ordinary coordinates, WLOG.

The linear combination

$$(1-\lambda)(ax^2+2fxy+by^2+2dy+2ex+c)+\\
\lambda(gx^2+2mxy+hy^2+2ky+2lx+j)=0$$

describes a pencil of conics which have the same four points in common. For three particular values of $\lambda$ the conic degenerates to a pair of straight lines ($(AB,CD),(AC, BD),(AD,BC)$). It takes a cubic equation to obtain these values.

---

Alternatively, by a suitable combination of the two equations, you can eliminate the terms in $y^2$ and express $y$ in terms of $x$. Then plugging $y$ in one of the initial equation, you will end-up with a quartic equation, which is solvable analytically.

Note that in the classical resolution method of the quartic, you factor as the product of two quadratics, by means of a resolvent equation of the third degree. These just correspond to the degeneracy equation and pairs of straight lines as in the pencil method.