# Get parameters for given point on quadratic bezier triangle

Tags: quadratics, bezier-curve

I have a 2 dimensional quadratic bezier triangle described by the position of its corners $v_0$, $v_1$ and $v_2$ and a handle for each side $h_0$, $h_1$ and $h_2$.

The parametric equation with the parameters $t_0$, $t_1$ and $t_2 = 1-t_0-t_1$ is:

$p = v_0 {t_0}^2 + v_1 {t_1}^2 + v_2 {t_2}^2 + 2 h_0 t_1 t_2 + 2 h_1 t_2 t_0 + 2 h_2 t_0 t_1$

I wanna find $t_0$, $t_1$ and $t_2$ for a given $p$.

I know it is possible to solve it numerically and that it is generally not possible to find the exact point. But I think it should be possible with quadratic bezier triangles as it might be possible to reduce it to a quartic or just cubic equation.

Comment: This entry should be relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175380/solution-af-a-system-of-2-quadratic-equations