# Solving a pair of quadratic equations for two unknowns efficiently

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots

I have a pair of quadratic equations in the form

$ax^2 + bx + cy^2 + dy + e = 0$

$fx^2 + gx + hy^2 + ky + l = 0$

and there should be a solution in the range $-2 \leq x,y \leq 2$
which I need to find programmatically.

I can eliminate one variable by squaring to get a quartic equation which I could solve numerically and substitute back, but I'm not sure about numeric stability and spurious roots.  Is there a better way of solving this?

Edit: This question [Solution af a system of 2 quadratic equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175380/solution-af-a-system-of-2-quadratic-equations) has answers with comments "In order to solve this degree 4 equation you need either some luck, or some patience " and "How would one programatically find the lines that constitute a degenerate conic?". That does not seem to demonstrate a better/simpler solution.

Comment: do you have concrete values for all the parameters?

Comment: Use **\ge** or **\geq** to generate $\geq$ and **\geqslant** to generate $\geqslant$. Or, use **\le** or **\leq** to generate $\leq$ and **\leqslant** to generate $\leqslant$. If you are old-fashioned, use **\gtrless** to generate $\gtrless$. Now, you are set with all the inequality signs. The words in bold are called *commands*, and all you need to do is put a dollar sign before and after the commands to put them into action, i.e. $\$\ldots\$$.

Comment: The Jenkins-Traub algorithm should provide acceptable numerical results for the roots of a quartic.  If you're really concerned, you can use the roots Jenkins-Traub finds and use them as initial guesses for Newton-Raphson iteration.

Comment: Thanks, the Jenkins-Traub algorithm looks like the best option at the moment. I will have concrete values for all parameters and need to solve this using C++ with real-time constraints, so want to avoid a slowly converging iterative process.